# Strange Behevior when trying to create a Template containing maps

Tags: c++

I am new to Templates and I tried to implement a template class which uses a map (which is a member in private). The map can only do 3 things: insert, swap, and operator =. And I don't get the full functionality of map..

Here's the code:

```
#include <map>
using namespace std;
template <class T,class SortKey, class SearchKey>
class GarageDataBase
{
public :

 GarageDataBase();
 virtual ~GarageDataBase(); 
    const T& Top() const;
 bool Add(T data,SortKey key2, SearchKey key2);
 T Remove(SearchKey toRemove);
 T Find(SearchKey toFind) const;
 bool isEmpty()const;

private:
 multimap<SortKey,T> firstMap;
 multimap<SearchKey,pair<SortKey,T>*> secondMap;

};    

template <class T,class SortKey, class SearchKey>     
GarageDataBase<T,SortKey,SearchKey>::GarageDataBase()
{

}

template <class T,class SortKey, class SearchKey>   
GarageDataBase<T,SortKey,SearchKey>::~GarageDataBase()
{
}

template <class T,class SortKey, class SearchKey> 
const T& GarageDataBase<T,SortKey,SearchKey>::Top() const
{
 firstMap.
}
```

In the last function, when trying to get into firstMap methods, all I get is: insert, swap or, operator = .

How do I get to "first" or "second" in the map?

Comment: FYI, when entering code, it's best to paste in the code, highlight it, then click the "101010" button to achieve the proper formating and syntax highlighting.

Comment: `first` and `second` aren't methods of `std::multimap`, they are the two values of a `std::pair`. To use `first` and `second` you need to have a [reference to a] value in the map. You might want to use `.find(...)` or use an iterator into the map. It depends on what you are trying to do?

Comment: thanks of the replay, i'm trying to get to .begin() value of the firstMap and i just can't get to it, all i have there is insert and swap

Comment: just tried with iterator, still same insert and swap butno begin()

Comment: It sounds like you're using Intellisense/code completion to look for methods on multimap. These features have a tendency to get somewhat confused around template code - I wouldn't rely on them to tell if you if something is possible or not. Write something that you think should work, try to actually compile it, and see what the compiler tells you.

Comment: Is it only the IDE that says only those methods are available, or will it not actually compile if you use the method?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to operate with first and second, you have to get an element first from the multimap. You get an element with `firstMap.find()` or `firstMap.begin()`.

[Here you can find a good example use.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/multimap/find/)